# LESS mixin function, change mixin depending on class

Tags: less

I'm new to LESS and I would like to know what's the best solution to have a dynamic mixin. What I want to do is change the border color depending on the parent wrapper.
For exemple .letterList & .letterActive are inside a .azStores wrapper class. Here my mixin is set to @azStoresMainColor.
In my html the wrapper class is changing dynamically (categoryStores, floorStores...) and I want to change the color of the border depending on those wrapperClass.

Is there a nice solution to do that in LESS ? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
.grouplistBorderMixin() {
    border-top: 2px solid @azStoresMainColor;
}

.letterList div:nth-child(1) {
    .grouplistBorderMixin;
    box-sizing: border-box;
} 

.letterActive {
    text-align: center;
    height: 94px;
    line-height: 94px;
    .grouplistBorderMixin;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Simplest would be to statically create classes like `.azStores .letterActive`, `.categoryStores .letterActive` etc. Less compiler doesn't know anything about your structure during compilation and so it can't dynamically create only the required selectors/rules.

Comment: really ? no way to improve this with LESS ?

Comment: None that I can think of because as I said there is no way the compiler knows what's going to be present in your file.